# Is there a way to specify an isolation mode with az acr build?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I want to pass in `--isolation hyperv` to the az acr build, but I can't find an equivalent in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-build). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass in the isolation parameter to `az acr build`.

If you create a Azure DevOps build agent, you could create your docker image using whatever parameters you want, then push it to the container registry. Make sure to select a [v3 VM type if you wish to use Hyper-V isolation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/).