# Add --isolation process to azure acr build command

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-functions, acr

I want to pass in --isolation process to the az acr build, but cannot find a way to do it from Azure docs, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by isolation? please add more information

Comment: --isolation process is an argument that gets passed to a docker build command while building a docker image manually. I am trying to automate docker image building process via azure acr tasks.

Comment: @littyk Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436222/is-there-a-way-to-specify-an-isolation-mode-with-az-acr-build) with similar problem, it seems that you cannot pass the isolation parameter to az acr build command. No isolation parameter is provided in [az acr build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-build).

As workaround , you can define a task's steps in a YAML file. You can then run the task manually by passing the file to the [az acr run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr#az-acr-run) command.

Multi-step task definition in ACR Tasks provides a container-centric compute primitive focused on building, testing, and patching containers. ACR Tasks supports multi-step task declaration in standard YAML syntax.

The [build step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-reference-yaml) type supports isolation property. For a detailed guide, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-reference-yaml).